# wso2 api gateway in multitenant environment

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-api-manager

I have wso2 apim 2.1 where i am configuring multitenancy for different purposes, now I want to deploy several api gateways in public clouds , my issue here is developer/creator from unit A and another developer from unit B can see all gateways to deploy the API. Is there some way how to restrict gateway visibility between tenants so unit/tenant A is using eg.AWS gw only and unit/tenant B eg.Azure gw only  ?

Answer (score 0):

This not supported in APIM 2.x.x.

Comment: Is there some workaround to achieve it? Even with some external tools without touching the code? Or part of apim 3.x ( I am not going for apim 3.0 before 3.1 x.0 is dangerous )